# On "Who Wants to be a Millionaire?" what's the largest margin by which the audience has been incorrect?

Tags: game-show, who-wants-to-be-a-millionaire

When using the "ask the audience" lifeline, what's they largest margin by which the audience has been incorrect? For example, if the correct answer is C, and the answer the majority of the audience picked was A, what's largest value of percent_A-percent_C, and what was the question?

Comment: Does it matter which country it happened in?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you include non-English-language versions, the audience has been **100% unanimously wrong** [five times](https://millionaire.fandom.com/wiki/Audience%27s_Statistics#Highest_percentages_of_an_answer_being_wrong) (more info [here](https://millionaire.fandom.com/wiki/Ask_the_Audience#Trivia)).

## ¿Quién quiere ser millonario? (Costa Rica)

I was able to find [the video of Kendell Apiser](https://youtu.be/JkOtWWgznOI?t=3732) where the audience was unanimously wrong. This is the question:

> La palabra "cerámica" proviene del griego "Keramiké" que significa, sustancia:
>
> A: Maleable
> B: Terrosa
> C: Brillante
> D: Quemada

Translation:

> The word "cerámica" comes from the Greek "Keramiké" which means ____ substance.
>
> A: Malleable
> B: Earthy
> C: Brilliant
> D: Burned

100% of the audience voted for

> C. The answer was really D.

I also found the video of [the other time](https://youtu.be/6wD2rW6y-9M?t=1497) the audience was unanimously wrong on the Costa Rican version, with Eduardo Cerdás, which was this question:

> La palabra "orquesta" proviene del griego "orkhéstra", que significa:
>
> A: Armonía musical
> B: Escenario infinito
> C: Lugar para danzar
> D: Salón de músicos

Translation:

> The word "orquesta" comes from the Greek "orkhéstra", which means:
>
> A: Musical harmony
> B: Infinite scenario
> C: Place to dance
> D: Hall of musicians

100% of the audience voted for

> A, but the answer was C.

## Ai là triệu phú (Vietnam)

The Vietnamese game also had several games where the audience was unanimously wrong. Thanks to the [Vietnamese wiki](https://ailatrieuphu.fandom.com/vi/wiki/Ph%E1%BA%A1m_Th%E1%BB%8B_Thu) for the show, we know that Phạm Thị Thu was given this question, used 50:50, then asked the audience:

> Tên ngọn thác Đambri hùng vĩ của núi rừng Tây Nguyên có ý nghĩa là gì?
>
> A: Đợi chờ
> <s>B: Bất khuất
>
> C: Sương khói</s>
> D: Chung thủy

Translation:

> What is the meaning of [the name of] the majestic Dambri waterfall of the Central Highlands?
>
> A: Wait
> <s>B: Indomitable
>
> C: Smog</s>
> D: Faithful

The answer is

> A, but the audience answered D. For an explanation of this, see [here](https://www.vietnam-travel.org/destinantions/dambri-waterfall-the-love-story-of-waiting.html)

[Đặng Thu Thảo](https://ailatrieuphu.fandom.com/vi/wiki/%C4%90%E1%BA%B7ng_Thu_Th%E1%BA%A3o) also used 50:50, then asked the audience. She somehow got the question right, unlike everyone else on this list:

> Nhân vật nào không nằm trong danh sách 100 người có tầm ảnh hưởng lớn nhất thế giới năm 2018 do tạp chí Time bình chọn?
>
> <s>A: Diễn viên Nicole Kidman
>
> B: Vận động viên quần vợt Roger Federer</s>
> C: Thủ tướng Jacinda Ardern
> D: Tổng thống Vladimir Putin

Translation:

> Which person is not on the list of the 100 most influential people in the world in 2018 voted by Time magazine?
>
> <s>A: Actor Nicole Kidman
>
> B: Tennis athlete Roger Federer</s>
> C: Prime Minister Jacinda Ardern
> D: President Vladimir Putin

The correct answer is:

> D, but the audience picked C

Lastly, there is [Nguyễn Thu Huyền](https://ailatrieuphu.fandom.com/vi/wiki/Nguy%E1%BB%85n_Thu_Huy%E1%BB%81n) who got this question:

> Thác Khe Vằn nằm ở tỉnh nào của nước ta?
>
> A: Thanh Hóa
> <s>B: Lai Châu
>
> C: Hà Giang</s>
> D: Quảng Ninh

Translation:

> Khe Van Waterfall is located in which province of our country?
>
> A: Thanh Hoa
> <s>B: Lai Chau
>
> C: Ha Giang</s>
> D: Quang Ninh

The correct answer is:

> D, but everyone chose A

## Who Wants To Be A Millionaire (US)

You're probably at least curious what the US record is. A good candidate for the biggest difference is [this question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klolmg4HeKE) about what the "M" in "RMS Titanic" stands for. The answer is:

> "mail" (2%) not "monarch" (91%)

Comment: The ceramics one made me curious. Is there any reason why Brilliant would have been logical? It seemed like a surprising pick for me, yet everyone made it.

Comment: @Kvothe: Ceramics are often glazed with a shiny finish.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_glaze).  (In hindsight it makes sense that it's not that; unglazed ceramics like a clay flower pot are also a thing, and probably more common historically when the technology first needed a name.)